# zero argument constructor. Why and where?

Tags: java, android

I have a constructor:

```
public class Question {



String question;
boolean correctAnswer;


public Question(String question, boolean correctAnswer)
{
    this.question = question;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
```

}

In mainActivity i want to display the question, but I get the zero argument constructor error:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button mYes;
Button mNo;
TextView mQuestion;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mYes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mNo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    //question list
    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    //adding question
    questions.add(first);
    //show the question.
    mQuestion.setText((CharSequence) questions.get(0));


}
//Creating question
Question first = new Question("Do i understand this code?", false);
```

I know that i have to create some kind of an empty constructor somewhere. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html probably answers my question, however I am not the best at english and i just cant understand how to implement the code i need.

Comment: Please post the exact text of your error message.  Also this is Java, not C++

Comment: Note the ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>(); should be new ArrayList<Question>();

Comment: Where do you have this code `Question first = new Question("Do i understand this code?", false);`? You are using it in `onCreate`

Comment: I added the missing question. Not the error says: Question cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence. But without the charsequence it shows the unresolved method on questions.get(0).

Comment: Please see my answer. It should solve your problem.

Comment: @Blackbelt It could be argued for historical stylistic consistency, but that is about it.

Comment: @Zéychin it is possible since api 19. It wasn't before.

Comment: @Blackbelt: didn't know. I see it has been added in Java 7.

Comment: @Blackbelt Right. Just saying for coders' sakes who have not gotten up-to-date or for consistency consistency within a project. Just from a project standards point of view (otherwise you have to go back and update all of the existing uses of generics in the project to maintain consistency). That's all. It would be a pretty weak argument not to use modern language features though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`questions.get(0)` return an object of type `Question`. You can't convert it into `CharSequence`.

Change this

```
mQuestion.setText((CharSequence) questions.get(0));
```

to

```
mQuestion.setText(questions.get(0).question);
```

**NOTE** If `Question` class isn't in same package as `MainActivity` then either make the properties of `Question` public or create getter method for them.

Also make sure you are using this code

```
Question first = new Question("Do i understand this code?", false);
```

before you are using it in `questions.add(first);` otherwise you will get `NullPointerException` in `mQuestion.setText(questions.get(0).question);`

Answer (score -1):

Bisides what Rohit5k2 writes.

This is java. Then you first create de object and the you can invoke it. According to your code, on method onCreate not exits the object called first because this is created out of the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
//Creating question
Question first = new Question("Do i understand this code?", false);
//question list
ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
//adding question
questions.add(first);
//show the question.
mQuestion.setText((CharSequence) questions.get(0).getQuestion());
```

Where, `getQuestion()` is a method of Question class:

```
public String getQuestion() {
    return this.question;
}
```